"jf rt build-promote" with comment containing spaces in Jenkins pipeline fails
I am using "Jenkins JFrog Plugin" in a pipeline, where I promote a build with the comment option.
I have not been able to find a way to run this with spaces in the comment.
jf("""rt build-promote --copy=true --comment="Promoted In Jenkins" ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} test_stable""")

This gives an error about wrong number of arguments
/usr/local/bin/jf rt build-promote --copy=true --comment='A Commment' TheJobName 48 test_stable
14:59:21  12:59:21 [Error] Wrong number of arguments (4). You can read the documentation at https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli

I have also tried:
jf("rt build-promote --comment=\"Promoted In Jenkins\" ... ")
jf("rt build-promote --comment='Promoted In Jenkins' ... ")

It works on a command line
 jf rt build-promote --copy=true --comment='Promoted Locally with Space' TestBuild 49 test_stable
 ->
16:57:05 [*Info] Promoting build...
16:57:05 [*Info] Promoted build TestBuild/49 to: test_stable repository.

Question related to the comment:
Where is this comment visible in artifactory? I cannot find it. When using "Jenkins Artifactory Plugin" and adding a comment to promotion, the information is visible under the "Release History" tab of the build-info.

You can use arguments with white-spaces in the jf step by following this syntax:
jf(['rt', 'build-promote', "${env.JOB_NAME}", "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", 'libs-release-local', '--copy=true', '--comment=Promoted In Jenkins'])

This approach ensures that the spaces within the argument are handled correctly.
For more information, you can check out the official documentation here.

Above example does not work for me. But I got it to work by
jf(['rt', 'build-promote', '--copy=true', '--comment=Promoted In Jenkins', "${env.JOB_NAME}", "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", 'test_stable']) i.e no double quotes around the comment.
